# Node.jsでの非同期処理をどのタイミングで行うべきか分からない

Tags: mysql, node.js

### TL;DR

クラスの呼び出しで非同期処理をしたいけど、どこで `async/await` すればいいのかわからない。

### 背景

データベースを含むWebアプリをNode.jsで作ろうとしています。
データベースへのアクセスをindex.jsでしてしまうと長くなってしまうので、別ファイルにクラスを作って、そこで処理をしてindex.jsで呼び出すということをやろうと思いました。
以下、極限まで簡略化したコードです。

*index.js*

```
const SQL=require('./SQL')
const sql = new SQL()

console.log(sql.q('SELECT * FROM users'))
```

*SQL.js*

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

class SQL {
  constructor() {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
      // 接続
    })
    this.connection.connect()
  }

  async q(stm) {
    this.stm = stm
    this.connection.query(this.stm, (err, res, field) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log('[ERROR]' + err.stack)
      } else {
        console.log(res)
        return res
      }
    })
  }
}
module.exports = SQL
```

*出力*

```
undefined
(resのデータ)
```

### やりたいこと

`undefined` をresのデータにしたいが、どこですればいいのかわからない。呼び出すとき？return するとき？

Comment: 質問する前にググって調べてみましたか？　https://qiita.com/tatsumi44/items/4b0fe912a49025591945 の「Mysql2/promiseを使いasync/awaitで書く」とか

Comment: 一応一通りググっては見ましたが調べ方が下手なのか何もできませんした。あとバカなんでわからないのですがこれは質問と関係のある記事なのでしょうか？確かにSQLでasync/awaitを使う方法について論じてありますが、自分にはこれをどう活用してこの質問を解決すればいいのかわかりません。

Comment: 紹介した記事はあなたの疑問「どこで async/await すればいいのかわからない」に答えてませんか？

Comment: @WebSurfer 提示の記事で解説されているのは `mysql2` という別のライブラリのようですが、それでも同じ使用方法で大丈夫ですか？

Comment: 「同じ使用方法で大丈夫」とは言ってませんが？

Answer (score 2):

非同期と言えばasync/awaitを使う…みたいなことを習ったのかも知れませんが、JavaScriptの歴史的にはasync/awaitは新しい機能で、どんな非同期関数に対してもそのまま使える物ではないと言うことを知っておく必要があります。

JavaScriptの非同期関数には大きく二つのタイプがあります。

1. コールバックを呼び出す非同期関数(コールバック関数) 例: [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)
2. Promiseを返す非同期関数(プロミスベース) 例: [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/fetch)

かつて、非同期関数と言えばコールバック関数しかありませんでした。コールバック関数でも非同期は実現出来ましたが、コードがコールバックだらけになるコールバック地獄に陥ることが多々ありました。このコールバック地獄を回避するために開発されたのがPromise(ECMAScript2015より)であり、Promiseをより簡単に使うために開発されたのがasync/await(ECMAScript2017より)です。そのようなこともあって、最近のライブラリではプロミスベースの非同期関数を実装することが多くなりました。

ひとつ注意してほしいのは、async/awaitはプロミスベース、つまり、Promiseを返す非同期関数に対してしか使えないと言うことです。コールバック関数に対して直接async/awaitを使うことはできません。

さて、質問のコードで使用している[mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)がどうなのかというと、このライブラリは古くからあることもあり、コールバック関数で非同期を実装しています。つまり、 **そのままasync/awaitで使うことはできません** 。ではどうするかというと、選択肢は三つです。

1. async/awaitを使わず、コールバックで実装する。
   昔からある方法です。古い本やサイトを見れば実例が載っています。
2. コールバック関数をラップするPromiseを返す関数を作る。
   コールバック関数のPromise化はよくある手法なので、調べれば多くの事例が見つかります。
3. プロミスベースの実装をしている別のライブラリを使う。
   たとえば、[mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper)にはプロミスベースの関数が用意されています。

お勧めは3.ですが、そのようなライブラリが見つからない事もよくあることです。そのような場合は、2.のPromise化を自分で行うのが良いでしょう。1.は古いコードでしかみなくなりつつあります。